# How to cache data on Android

Tags: android, caching, background-process

I'm developing a messaging app using firebase for practice. Everything is working properly. But the only problem is loading all data everytime when the user restarts the app taking a long time and internet. So I want to store those data in cache and also do some operations in background. When the user restarts the app I want to display all data without reloading from server again. Even in offline mode.

Operations I do to get list items data when the user starts the app,

- First I get the firebase username of the user.
- Then from server I get the contact names of the user.
- I go to message database between the current user(client) and the contact.
- Then I get the last timestamp and message.
- On client side I sort the timestamp and display it in a listview.

My current contacts count is 4. It takes 4-6sec to load data and display in a listview. So I want to do these process in background and keep my listview updated to enable offline cache of all data just like other popular apps (e.g. telegram, kik)

Please suggest some sources or little explanation on how to do it.

Thank you !

Comment: Java is not Android.

Comment: sorry @Ungeheuer

Comment: Don't worry. It's a common mistake because their syntax appears similar. Just remember it and spread the word.